# Java Spring CSRF token verification issue on multi tab

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I have implemented the CSRF protection in my application using Spring security 3.2.0. Code below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
}
```

Also we have used Spring MVC  in our JSP forms. As a results the CSRF token will be generated for each post request form. This was working perfect , but recently we noticed that when a user access the website using multiple tabs from same browser the different CSRF tokens clashes and user gets the CSRF token not found error.
Steps:
1. user log into a the site from a tab and on any page. CSRF token is generated for the page.
2. User opens another tab and access the same website , another CSRF token is generated
3. User goes back to tab 1 and submits the page. User gets CSRF token mismatch error.

I have gone through other forums, and learned that my application is generating the token per request. and changing it to per session will salve this problem. However I could not find the actual code/steps I need to follow to implement this solution. Request you to guide me for the same.

Comment: As far as I know and also found in spring documentation, the token is valid throughout the HTTP session, it should not be different for each request. See here more details: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-timeouts. How come that you have a different token for each request, how is it generated?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have verified the CSRF token for both the pages on different tabs , and both are different.